# Probability of picking two standard trig functions whose graphs never intersect

Tags: probability, combinatorics, trigonometry

> Suppose you are given a set $S$ that contains the six standard trigonometric functions $$S=\{\sin(x), \cos(x), \tan(x), \cot(x), \sec(x), \csc(x)\}$$
>
> What is the probability given the 6 standard trigonometric functions, where defined on the reals, you pick a pair of two that never intersect (assume order does not matter)?

My thought process was that since $\sin(x)$ and $\sec(x)$ never intersect, and $\cos(x)$ and $\csc(x)$ never intersect, then the probability is $2/15$. But the answer ended up being $4/15$.

I thought that order didn't matter, so unless I missed some cases, I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Pythagorean identity $\sec^2 x = \tan^2 x + 1$, so $\sec$ and $\tan$ never intersect. Similarly $\csc$ and $\cot$ never intersect.

Comment: sec(x) = tan(x) => 1/cos(x) = sin(x)/cos(x) => 1 = sin(x), no?

Comment: Unless it's not defined because of division by 0?

Comment: Yeah, if $\sin x=1$ then $\cos x=0$ and so $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ are undefined.